# Sonos cancelAudioClip API returns 415 HTTP response

Tags: sonos

I am able to play an audio clip, but when I try to cancel the clip using the documented API I get a 415 unsupported media type error  w/ the following error text:

RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type

The confusing part is the request is a HTTP DELETE verb, and I am providing no attached body/content as none is required by the API (https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/audioclip/cancelaudioclip/).

Please note there is an inconsistency in the SONOS documentation between the API described as '/players/{playerId}/audioClip/{id}' and the example at the bottom of the page which includes a household in the path.

Here's an example of the API I send:
https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/players//audioClip/<clip ID - a UUID from the play clip response>

Is there some trick to make it work? Is this a bug in the SONOS implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Edit 8/2/2021: I have checked internally and this API is not available via the Cloud, only via the LAN. I will ask to have this page removed from the Cloud Control API documentation.

The first error you are seeing (RESTEASY) is caused by not explicitly setting a Content-Type header in the request - this is required even on requests that have no body/content. The value of the header should be application/json, like this:

Content-Type: application/json

Once you add the Content-Type header, you will get the following error:

```
{"errorCode":"ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_COMMAND","reason":"Command not found"}
```

This is expected as this API is not available via the Cloud Control API. I have asked internally when this functionality will be enabled via the cloud, but there is no plan or timeline to add it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added an empty JSON body to the DELETE API.

I tried both API forms and get command not found errors for both APIs:

The household API:
 DELETE https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/households/<MY HOUS ID>/players/<My Player ID>/audioClip/<CLIP ID>

returns: 404 - {"errorCode":"ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_COMMAND","reason":"Command not found"}

The device only API:
DELETE https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/players/<My Player ID>/audioClip/<CLIP ID>

returns: 404 - {"errorCode":"ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_COMMAND","reason":"Command not found"}

Comment: Hi @gambitx28 - I have updated my original answer with some clarifications. The summary is the first error (RESTEASY) was due to the missing Content-Type header, the second error (ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_COMMAND) is because this API is not available in the Cloud Control API, and unknown when it will be added. I will ask to have it removed from the documentation.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to stop an audio clip that has started playing?  i.e. clips can be started, but not stopped, correct?

Comment: @gambitx28 - that is correct, and there is no ETA on when that functionality will be available via the Cloud Control API. If you are interested in working with the LAN Control API, which does have the ability to cancel an audio clip, you can reach out to developer-feedback@sonos.com.